# how to set path so that they work on both localhost and remote server

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have an app that is working fine in localhost.  On remote server I have uploaded it to a sub folder.  Some of the relative paths are not working.  My question is what is the best practice in defining relative paths, so that they work on local and remote server.

Comment: If you're laravel project is into subfolder on remote server then you need to create htaccess and define public path in there

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a relative path for links

Example :

```
<a href="{{ '/' . 'home' }}">{{ __('home') }}</a>
```

OR By route name

```
<a href="{{ route('home') }}">{{ __('home') }}</a>
```

This will work for any where you set project.

Comment: Currently I am using "<a href="{{ url('/path') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Do something</a>" in my blade files and jquery.  And to access file in public_html in the controller I am using "$tmpname = './tmp/file_to_create_or_read';"  Is this approach ok ?
"

Comment: Instead of use url() it is more flexible to use route(). and for access public path you may use like public_path('/home') method of laravel.